# Elliptic Curve and Divisor Example help (Step 3)

Tags: elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am reading [this paper](http://math.uni.lu/eml/projects/reports/Bachelor-Thesis-Dias-da-Cruz.pdf), specifically Example 2.3 on page 9, and am having a few problems understanding a part of it

> We construct an elliptic curve $E$ on $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ defined by $y^2=x^3+4x$ with a point at infinity $\mathcal{O}$
>
> We then find a divisor of $E$ $$D=\left[(0,0)\right]+\left[(2,4)\right]+\left[(4,5)\right]+\left[(6,3)\right]-4\left[\mathcal{O}\right]$$
>
> We can then say that:
>   $$\begin{align}\text{div}(y-2x)&=\left[(0,0)\right]+2\left[(2,4)\right]-3\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\\
> \text{div}(x-2)&=\left[(2,4)\right]+\left[(2,-4)\right]-2\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\end{align}$$
>
> We can then replace various elements in the definition of $D$ with these divisors:
>
> $$\begin{align}D&=\left[(0,0)\right]+\left[(2,4)\right]+\left[(4,5)\right]+\left[(6,3)\right]-4\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\\
> &=\left[(2,4)\right]+\text{div}\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)+\left[(4,5)\right]+\left[(6,3)\right]-3\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\\
> &=\left[(2,-4)\right]+\text{div}\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)+\left[(2,4)\right]+\text{div}\left(\frac{y+x+2}{x-2}\right)-2\left[\mathcal{O}\right]\\
> &=\text{div}\left(x-2\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y+x+2}{x-2}\right)\end{align}$$

However, what I don't understand are the following steps:

> $$\begin{align} 
> D&=\text{div}\left(x-2\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y+x+2}{x-2}\right)\\
>  &=\text{div}\left(\frac{(y-2x)(y+x+2)}{x-2}\right)\\
>  &=\text{div}\left(x^{2}-y\right)\end{align}$$

Can anyone help explain to me how they have come to this conclusion please

---

This question comes in 3 parts:

- Step 1 - [Elliptic Curve and Divisor Example help (Step 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168358/401264)
- Step 2 - [Elliptic Curve and Divisor Example help (Step 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168747/401264)
- Step 3 - This one

Comment: Is the part you're missing that $\text{div}(f\cdot g) = \text{div}(f) + \text{div}(g)$?

Comment: That covers the first equality, thanks, but I'm still confused by the second one

Comment: Multiply it out, and then replace $y^2$ with $x^3+4x$

Comment: Brilliant - thanks. I'd multiplied it out but not realised I could substitute in a value for $y^2$. Makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion:

$$\begin{align} 
D&=\text{div}\left(x-2\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)+\text{div}\left(\frac{y+x+2}{x-2}\right)\\
&=\text{div}\left((x-2)\left(\frac{y-2x}{x-2}\right)\left(\frac{y+x+2}{x-2}\right)\right)\tag{div$(f\cdot g)=$ div$f+$ div$g$}\\
&= \text{div}\left(\frac{(x-2)(y-2x)(y+x+2)}{(x-2)^2}\right)\tag{multiply out}\\
&= \text{div}\left(\frac{(y-2x)(y+x+2)}{x-2}\right)\tag{cancel $(x-2)$}\\
&= \text{div}\left(\frac{-2x^2-xy-4x+y^2+2y}{x-2}\right)\tag{multiply out}\\
&= \text{div}\left(\frac{-2x^2-xy-4x+\left(x^3+4x\right)+2y}{x-2}\right)\tag{substitute $y^2=x^3+4x$}\\
&= \text{div}\left(\frac{-2x^2-xy+x^3+2y}{x-2}\right)\tag{simplify numerator}\\
&=\text{div}\left(x^2-y\right)\tag{simplify fraction}
\end{align}$$