# Division of polynomials in more than one variable

Tags: polynomials

I have previously done division of polynomials in one variable, where I would do the following:

> To compute $$\frac{x^3+4x^2+x-2}{x+1}$$
>
> I would write 
>   $$\begin{align}x^3+4x^2+x-2&=(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c)\\
> &= ax^3 + bx^2+cx+ax^2+bx+c\\
> &= ax^3 + (a+b)x^2+(b+c)x+c
> \end{align}$$
>
> Equating coefficients gives us the following systems:
>   $$\begin{align}a&=1\\
> a+b &= 4\\
> b+c &= 1\\
> c &= -2
> \end{align}$$
>
> From this we can see that 
>   $$\begin{align}a&=1\\
> b &= 3\\
> c &= -2
> \end{align}$$
>
> Therefore we conclude that $$\frac{x^3+4x^2+x-2}{x+1} = x^2+3x-2$$

How would I go about calculating something similar but in more than one variable, say
$$\frac{x^3-2x^2-xy+2y}{x-2}$$

I want to be able to write this as $$x^3-2x^2-xy+2y=(x-2)A$$ where $A$ is some polynomial wih unknown coefficients

My question is, what form should this $A$ take?

[Note: This came about as part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166890/401264)]

Comment: Treat $y$ as just any other constant and run the algorithm as usual. $A$ will just be a polynomial in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\,$ should take the form $\,x^2+bx+cy\,$ where $\,b,c\,$ could either be constants or involve $\,y$

But for this problem, you can just do it directly,

$$x^3-2x^2-xy+2y= x^2(x-2)-y(x-2)=(x-2)(x^2-y)$$

If $\,y\,$ is a perfect square, then

$$x^3-2x^2-xy+2y=(x-2)(x+\sqrt y)(x-\sqrt y)$$

Comment: Do we not also need an $xy$ term in $A$?

Comment: @lioness99a If $b$ involves $y$ after the calculation, then there will be $xy$ term

Answer (score 0):

Note that division in the polynomial ring $R[x,y]$, is like to division in $(R[y])[x]$. So you may put 
$$A=x^2+ay^2+bxy. $$
Note that since the degree of $y$ in the polynomial $x^3-2x^2-xy+2y$ is $1$, so immediately $a=0$.